# Applying JQuery plugin to new elements inserted into DOM through AJAX using each()

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm using the JQuery plugin `customSelect()` http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/ to style dropdown boxes.

If I initialize the script more than once on the same elements, they cease to work.  I need to figure out a way to only initialize the plugin on newly created elements inserted into the DOM through AJAX.

So, I initialize it on all drop downs (the desired effect) -

```
$('select').customSelect();
```

and elements that I select this plugin work for are given a class of "hasCustomSelect", like so

```
<select class="hasCustomSelect"></select>
```

but if I initialize twice -

```
$('select').customSelect();
$('select').customSelect();
```

it will literally stop working.

So, in my AJAX request, I have it initializing on elements WITHOUT that class, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is the AJAX -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'wp-content/themes/themetitle/functions/get-child.php',
    data: { childID : theID, URL : theURL, classlevel : classlevel },
        beforeSend:function() {

        },
        success:function(data) {
            $('#makesort').append(data); 
            makesort(); 
            $.each('select', function() {
                if( $(this).hasClass('hasCustomSelect') ) {
                    //DO NOTHING!  
                } else {
                    $(this).customSelect(); 
                }
            });
        },
        error:function() {

        }   
    });
```

So, the thought I had was after the `data` is appended to my `div`, I'll go through each `<select>` element, determine if it already contains the class `hasCustomSelect`, and if not, then initialize the plugin for this element.

This doesn't seem to have the desired effect, however, and in fact, it's producing an error.  There are probably several ways to see if a plugin is already applied, but I thought checking to see if the default class that's added is there would be sufficient.

Comment: What is the error you mentioned?

Comment: It produces an error typical of poor syntax, like "cannot define top of null" on Jquery.min.js, which makes me believe it's a syntax error more than anything, like I'm missing a bracket or using `each` wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your each:

```
$('select:not(.hasCustomSelect)').each(function() {
    $(this).customSelect(); 
});
```

or...

```
$.each($('select:not(.hasCustomSelect)'), function() {
    $(this).customSelect();
});
```

The reason you're getting an error is because the first parameter to `$.each(...` is a collection of objects, not a selector.

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhh, perfect!  I figured it was a syntax error of sorts.  Will mark answered ASAP.  Thanks for the explanation as well!

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, there is a way to mark the answer as "accepted" which is different from voting up. :)

Comment: I know, I said I will mark answered ASAP.  It makes you wait ;)